# Placing JSON retrieved image urls inside <li> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, tags

I have a working JSON response with the following code:

In my html, I have:

```
<ol id="selectable"></ol>
```

In javascript I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// json response ...
if (response.success) {
    $.each(response.data.photos, function(i,photo){
        $("<img/>").attr("src", photo.image_url).appendTo("#selectable");
        if ( i == 20 ) return false;
    });       
}
```

This gives me:

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <img src="a.jpg">
    <img src="b.jpg">
    <img src="c.jpg">               
</ol>
```

But what I want is a list like this:

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <li><img src="a.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="b.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="c.jpg"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: If you want a `li` element, you have to create it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("<img/>").attr("src", photo.image_url).wrap('<li>').appendTo("#selectable");
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
("#selectable").append("<li><img src = "+photo.image_url+" /></li>");
```

instead of

```
$("<img/>").attr("src", photo.image_url).appendTo("#selectable");
```